# View Controller not getting called

Tags: ember.js

I have set up a view in ember and rendered it on the page like this

```
App.TestView = Ember.View.extend({
   template: Ember.Handlebars.compile('<h1>Heading</h1>')
});

{{view App.TestView}}
```

But if I create the controller nothing happens

```
App.TestController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    init: function() {
        console.log('CONTROLLER HERE');
        this._super();
    }
});
```

Any ideas why this happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a view manually (like you are doing) it doesn't use the test controller.  If you hit a test route it will use the associated test controller and test view.

In your case based on your comments below you probably want to set up some routes and have them use the associated controllers and views.

Check out this: http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/defining-your-routes/

Maybe something like this

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('gallery', { path: '/gallery/:gallery_id' }, function() {
     this.resource('photo', { path: 'photo/:photo_id' });
  });
});
```

Comment: So, I can't use a controller with it? It's just a little widget. OR should i be using components for that?

Comment: @connor.js, a component has also no associated controller per default,  what data do you need your controller to hold?

Comment: Well, the actual goal it to talk to a slideshow view when i click on this view, but i think you can only do that by communicating between controllers

Comment: You're probably better off creating routes, like a slideshow resource, and picture resource underneath the slideshow resource etc.

Comment: @connor.js, as kingpin2k states, a slideshow is a perfect candidate for having routes to move between your slides and having your correspondent controllers holding transient data your slides might need etc.

Comment: @intuitivepixel but then when you press back button you'll have to go back through hundreds of pictures....

Comment: no, your back button can go back to the last picture gallery/1/photos/12 back to gallery/1/photos/11

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a route for your example to work: http://jsbin.com/IGIvuhe/2/edit

Add this and it will work:

```
App.Router.map(function(){
  this.route("test", {path: '/'});
});
```

Hope it helps.